# leverage() diagnostic test not supported for glmmTMB models in r

Tags: r, outliers, glmmtmb, leverage, poisson-distribution

I am using a `glmmTMB` to look at the effect of numerous variables on how far individuals travel (`distance`).

The example below is one of many datasets I am working with, all of which have the same underlying structure and problems.

Some details about the data (full data [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d)):

- My response variable (`distance`) is overdispersed and shows some degree of zero-inflation
- All outliers are real values
- Numerical explanatory variables included in model were mean centered and standardized within year and location prior to exporting
- `distance` is not an integer, but I force it to be by rounding to the nearest whole number. As such, I have been using `family=nbinom2`
- `juv.density` and `local.density` are correlated (Pearson's r = -0.73). We have kept them both in the model as per [Morrissey and Ruxton (2018)](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Multiple-Regression-Is-Not-Multiple-Regressions%3A-of-Morrissey-Ruxton/a68c255c6ef8bab31a4f2d72cce2c4c8737c1930).

Sample of the data:

```
  individual distance sex     BDAY food.density juv.density local.density winter litter_id  year location
       <dbl>    <int> <fct>  <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>     <int> <dbl> <fct>   
1       6130       60 M      0.299     -1.11          0.341         1.26  -0.432      3057     0 KL      
2       6358        0 F     -1.40      -1.11          1.62          1.57  -0.432      3078     0 KL      
3       6391       75 F     -0.109     -1.11         -0.937        -0.893 -0.432      3058     0 KL      
4       6507       91 F     -0.177     -1.11         -0.937        -0.277 -0.432      3059     0 KL      
5       6528      361 F      0.865     -1.31         -1.13         -0.731 -0.432      3158     0 SU      
6       6551      205 M      0.665     -0.00232      -0.110        -1.14  -0.342      3353     1 SU
```

`glmmTMB` model and output:

```
move=glmmTMB(distance ~ sex + BDAY + food.density + juv.density + local.density + winter_pressure + (1|litter_id), data = dist_moved, family=nbinom2)

> summary(rec_dist)
 Family: nbinom2  ( log )
Formula:          juv_disp ~ sex + BDAY + food.density + juv.density + local.density + winter_pressure + (1 | litter_id)
Data: recruit_dist

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   804.6    824.3   -393.3    786.6       57 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 litter_id (Intercept) 0.51439  0.71721 
Number of obs: 66, groups:  litter_id, 49

Overdispersion parameter for nbinom2 family (): 1.03 

Conditional model:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      4.545794   0.226985 20.0268  < 2e-16 ***
sexM             0.656629   0.326061  2.0138  0.04403 *  
BDAY            -0.053503   0.196419 -0.2724  0.78532    
food.density    -0.195088   0.176946 -1.1025  0.27023    
juv.density      0.544409   0.267533  2.0349  0.04186 *  
local.density   -0.650974   0.268081 -2.4283  0.01517 *  
winter_pressure -0.368004   0.176681 -2.0829  0.03726 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This plot for `local.density` illustrates why I want to test how much leverage this extreme value has on my results:

[image]

My current attempts have used [this guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/model_evaluation.pdf) that works with the `DHARMa` package, but this code (taken from [page 15](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/model_evaluation.pdf)) only seems to allow me to look at the random effect (`litter_id`) not the response variable (i.e., `distance`). What am I missing?

```
owls_nb1_simres <- DHARMa::simulateResiduals(move)
plot(owls_nb1_simres)

source(system.file("other_methods","influence_mixed.R", package="glmmTMB"))

owls_nb1_influence_time <- system.time(
owls_nb1_influence <- influence_mixed(move, groups="litter_id")
)
car::infIndexPlot(owls_nb1_influence)
```

Cook's distance plot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is better documented at `?car::influence.mixed.models`

> groups: a character vector containing the name of a grouping factor
> or names of grouping factors; if more than one name is
> supplied, then groups are defined by all combinations of
> levels of the grouping factors that appear in the data. If
> omitted, then each individual row of the data matrix is
> treated as a "group" to be deleted in turn.

Equivalently, specifying `groups=".case"` deletes one observation at a time.

```
system.time(ii <- influence_mixed(move, groups=".case"))
## 11 seconds elapsed
car::infIndexPlot(ii)
```

If you wanted to check the sensitivity with respect to a particular observation, you could always

```
update(move, data = dist_moved[-11,])
```

and compare the coefficients.  You could also use `data = subset(dist_moved, local.density < -1.5)` or something similar based on `dplyr::filter` ...

It looks like `HLMdiag::leverage()` only works on linear mixed models. Faster influence measures would be possible if we could extract/efficiently compute the hat matrix for `glmmTMB` fits, which we [can't (yet)](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/391).

Comment: One follow-up question. When you set `groups=".case"` what do the numbers in the diagnostic plot correspond to? That is, the x-axis/index. Would they be the observation/row number?

Comment: Yes, that's right ...